# I Want To Include Two files in my PHP but I get warning saying ignoring session_start

Tags: php, session, include

I want to include two files using require_once. When I had only one file it worked fine but when I added second require_once it gives me the following error Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start().
I have tried adding this

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
session_start();}?>
```

But it didn't help.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show me the other files?

Comment: if(session_status() !==PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ){ session_start();  } follow this above snippet wherever your starting session .

Comment: you shouldn't ignore comments; they ask for clarification to which you didn't do and isn't very polite neither. Had you posted the code for your other file(s), those people up here would have most likely been able to answer your question.

Comment: My utmost apology to all I didn't mean to ignore anyone's comment. Sorry for disrespecting anyone here even if unintentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have session_start(); line in both files you include (and session_start() can be called only once). Try to replace them with the code you provided (not just add it) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use 'session_start();' once in the page, and all the included files, you load at the time.

the best way is to write a 'session_start();' at the top of the file where you are including all the other files and do NOT write a 'session_start();' in those files.

You could also generate a special file in which you write 'session_start();'
if you now do a

```
include_once('path_to_this_file.php');
```

or

```
require_once('path_to_this_file.php');
```

This file will only once be included and the session_start will also be executed only once.